# Some bootstrap features are not working fully in angular 6 project

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I used [this](https://medium.com/@beeman/tutorial-styling-angular-cli-v6-apps-with-bootstrap-8d4f8ea5adae) tutorial to add bootstrap to my newly created angular 6 project.

There is no error on compilation (neither in `ng console`  nor in developer tool of browser).

It seem to be working because button are well colored. But compare to original code, mine is different.

I copied this code in my application.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Styles</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>      
</div>
```

[image]

But what I get in my application is this:
[image]

I really don't know what is missing here. Any idea ?

Comment: if you remove `type="button"` from your code it works like before or give it `mr-2` class per button

Comment: Are you sure about the bootstrap versions are same with tutorial?

Comment: yep bro, you can use `mr-2` class for that

Answer (score 0):

The result in the snippet rendered buttons with white space characters and yours didn't.

I recommend you insert white space as html code. like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>&nbsp;
....
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Bootstrap with npm rather than importing it to your html.

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Comment: The question has the `bootstrap-4` tag.

Comment: this is not valid answer